# "key violation" autoincrement field in ClientDataSet [Delphi]

Tags: database, delphi, dbgrid

this is my third question here, so far excellent responses ^^

I'm having no problems in browsing, editing the data, but insertions...

Here is my doubt:
In a finance/stock software i have a form to create a new order,
naturally i need to insert a new row in **t_orders** table
and insert items in **t_orderitems** table with **orderId** field linked to a row in **t_orders**

```
CREATE TABLE `t_orders` (
    `orderId` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `clientId` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ...)

CREATE TABLE `t_orderitems` (
    `orderitemId` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `orderId` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ...)

--> INDEXES AND FOREIGN KEYS OMITTED <--
```

How do i add itemorders to a grid and finally in "FinalizeOrder" button click

- Create an order in **t_orders**
- Insert items in **t_orderitems** linked to that order

Connection is made using ADO.

I'm not sure if it's possible to do like this, in that case, how i should do?

edit: I tried using nested ClientDataSets and it works in parts, but i still don't know how to get the inserted Order Id

**edit2:**
*Now i have another problem, i can't add more than one item into the ClientDataSet.

Because OrderItemId is empty for all items (i can only get that values upon database insertion), when i attempt to add a second item it gives me Key Violation, any ideas??*

*If i set Updatemode to something different than upWhereKeyOnly and set pfInKey to False it works but i don't think it's an option*

*Any ideas?*

Thanks in advance!
Arthur.

Comment: Wich Database do you use? MySQL?

Comment: Yes, but i will change to PosgreSql on final version

Comment: Check the mysql function LAST_INSERT_ID(), see this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20847

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have an ADO dataset that gets data from your DB and is linked to the grid?  What you need to do this is an intermediate layer.

Create a TClientDataset and connect it to your ADO dataset, then connect the grid to the client dataset.  When a new order comes in, call Append on the client dataset and insert the data for the new order into it.  This will make it show up on the grid.  When you want to save your changes to the DB,  call .Update on the client dataset.  It'l use the ADO dataset it's linked to to send the updates to the DB.  Check the documentation on TClientDataset for explanations on how to set this all up; it's one of the few things in recent versions that's actually documented really well.

To update multiple tables, look at the documentation on master/detail relations and use two datasets like this, linked to each other.

Comment: Thank for the reply. What i'm trying to do here is recommended? And how do i set items orderId's?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I don't have any experience with AUTO_INCREMENT fields.

Answer (score 1):

If you make a master-details relationship between the two datasets in your application, ADO can handle it automatically. That means, once you insert a new record into master dataset (orders), you can insert new records in your details dataset (order_items) without the need to specify order_id, because order_id for the current record in master dataset will be automatically retrieved, and inserted in the newly inserted records of details dataset.

To make a master/details relationship between your datasets, if you are using AdoTable for detail dataset, you can set its MasterSource to a datasource connected to your master dataset, and define relatinship between the two datasets using MasterFields property.
If you are using AdoDataset or AdoQuery, you should set DataSource property in detail dataset to a datasource connected to your master dataset. Then you have to add a WHERE clause in your detail dataset's SQL statement using a SQL paramater with the same name as your key field in the master dataset. In your case it would be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM t_orderitems WHERE OrderID = :OrderID
```

Now you can set your relationship in MasterFields property of your detail dataset.

Since your orders can have multiple items, you can set LockType to ltBatchOptimistic in the detail dataset (order_items), so that once you insert a new item, it is not sent to database immediately. Using ltBatchOptimistic means your changes will be saved in client memory temporally until you call UpdateBatch method. UpdateBatch sends all the changes to the database.

If you want to cancel the order, you have to call CancelBatch method to cancel modifications done on detail dataset, and delete the created order record in master dataset manually.

Comment: I did that, but when i can't add multiple **Items** in the **Order**, i get “key violation” because 2 equal OrderItemId

Comment: If the field is defined as AutoInc in your table, then your database is responsible for providing a value for OrderItemID field, not you. You shouldn't pass any value for that field to your database. BTW, how do you insert items? do you use TDateset methods (e.g. Insert, Append), or do you write the Insert SQL statement manually?

Comment: I add to the ClientDataSet using append and i left the field OrderItemId empty (this is the problem because the ClientDataSet doesn't allow 2 equal ClientOrderId's)

Comment: OK, so you have a clientdataset which is connected to a datasetprovider, right? Why are you using ClientDataset here? is that a multi-tier application in which your clients are connected to an app server? Using an ADO dataset in batch mode provides a similar functionality in client/server applications, and doesn't have such a problem. But for ClientDataset I don't think there is any solution unless you handle auto incrementation manually.

Answer (score 0):

thanks RRUZ, this isn't exactly what i wanted (i still have to manually set all orderitems OrderId's manually before insertion), but will do it

```
with DataModule1.ADOQuery1 do
begin
  SQL.Text := 'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()';
  Open();
  First();
  LastInsertId := Fields[0].Value;
  Close();
end;
```